# Unpatching (Disable .APK Signature Verification & Signature verification status always true) in Lucky Patcher?

Tags: signature-error, lucky-patcher

I applied the patch (*Disable .apk Signature Verification* and *Signature verification status always true*) in Lucky Patcher by going to Lucky Patcher >> 
 ToolBox >> Apply Patch to Android.

Now I want to unpatch, but there is no option to do so kindly help!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because it has been applied to Xposed settings

You can do like so, to restore this setting to its default:

- Go to Toolbox >> Xposed settings and **untick**:

  - (1) **.apk Signature Verification**,
  - (2) **Signature Verification status always True** and then click apply.

---

Your device may reboot or not but after that it should show that the patch is not applied on respective options.

---

Alternatively just **disable ALL patches** already applied in Android via the Lucky Patcher:

- Toolbox >> **Untick**;

  - (1) *Remove all patches from core.jar* and
  - (2) *Remove all patches from services.jar*

Comment: Actually I was installing some apps and those apps were showing "App not installed error" That's why I applied the patch. But It didn't worked.Can you suggest me more help on this? Kindly provide me your WhatsApp or  other option to have chat and talk on this topic. I will appreciate your help on this. Awaiting for your reply.
Regards,
Sagar

Comment: They use different signatures? Have you tried resigning them with same signature, try decompiling them with Apktool then sign again

Comment: Actually , I don't have enough knowledge about app decompiling.Can you edit the app signatures so that It will install on any Android device? I can provide the link of the Application if you say.I will appreciate your help!